# Javascript check/uncheck all checkbox function only works when there is more than one checkbox

Tags: javascript

I've got a series of checkboxes set up as an array (name="action[]") and a JavaScript function linked to another checkbox to check/uncheck all of them.  It works fine when there are at least two checkboxes to be checked, but if there's only one it does nothing.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkall" id="checkall" class="box" onClick="doCheck(this, 'action');">

<input type="checkbox" name="action[]" id="action" value="' . $something['someid'] . '" class="box">
<input type="checkbox" name="action[]" id="action" value="' . $something['someid'] . '" class="box">
```

JavaScript:

```
function doCheck(mainChk, fields) {
  for(i = 0; i < mainChk.form.elements[fields].length; i++) {
    mainChk.form.elements[fields][i].checked = mainChk.checked;
  }
}
```

Comment: If there is only one checkbox, then `mainChk.form.elements[fields]` is not an array(-like structure).

Comment: I see -- is there a good way to check to see if that item is an array?

Comment: use `typeOf`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: Got it -- but then how to I make it check the one item if that's the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkall" id="checkall" class="box">

<input type="checkbox" name="action[]" id="action" value="' . $something['someid'] . '" class="box check-child">
<input type="checkbox" name="action[]" id="action" value="' . $something['someid'] . '" class="box check-child">
```

if you would like to use jquery, you could you this code:

```
$("#checkall").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
        $(".check-child").attr("checked", "checked");
    else
        $(".check-child").removeAttr("checked");
));
```

Comment: I'm certainly cool with using jQuery but I need the [] as this is being processed by PHP after submission.

Comment: Instead of using a name attribute, you could put a class on your inputs and use that as a selector instead. I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I like the idea but it doesn't seem to work and I'm not getting anything in Firefox's error console.

Comment: Never mind -- I had it inside a different JS include file.  Adding it to my existing jQuery form validation include makes it work like a champ.  Thanks!